# Difference between or and xor gate in usage

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuits

I'm trying to make a circuit diagram using an xor gate, but it seems that xor gates are implemented differently than or gates.  For example, just a simple diagram with an or gate is like the following:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.logic.US,positioning,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit logic US]
\node[or gate, inputs=nnnn] (or1) {};
\draw
    (or1.input 1) -- ++(-1,0) node[left] {$a$}
    (or1.input 4) -- ++(-1,0) node[left] {$b$}
    (or1.output) -- ++(0.5,0) node[right] {$y$}
;\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However, if I change the code to make an xor gate, such as:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.logic.US,positioning,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit logic US]
\node[xor gate, inputs=nnnn] (or1) {}; %change here from or gate to xor gate
\draw
    (or1.input 1) -- ++(-1,0) node[left] {$a$}
    (or1.input 4) -- ++(-1,0) node[left] {$b$}
    (or1.output) -- ++(0.5,0) node[right] {$y$}
;\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This causes the following error:

> ```
> ! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `input' (in 'input 4').
>
> See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
> Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
> ...                                    
> l.15  (or1.input 4)
>                 -- ++(-1,0) node[left] {$b$}
> ```

Is this a bug, missing feature, or something that I'm doing incorrectly?  Thank you for any help you can give.

Answer (score 5):

This is by design. An `xor gate` has fixed number of inputs, namely two. Also from the manual in the `shapes.gates.logic.US` section:

> The library defines a number of shapes. For each shape the allowed number of inputs is also shown:
>
> - `and` gate US, two or more inputs
> - `and` gate CDH, two or more inputs
> - `nand` gate US, two or more inputs
> - `nand` gate CDH, two or more inputs
> - `or` gate US, two or more inputs
> - `nor` gate US, two or more Inputs
> - **`xor` gate US, two inputs**
> - `xnor` gate US, two inputs
> - `not` gate US, one input
> - `buffer` gate US, one input

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, though I have to admit that it seems like a rather arbitrary design decision, since (for example) 3 input xor gates are commonly found, such as http://www.nxp.com/products/discretes-and-logic/logic/lvc/3-input-exclusive-or-gate-based-on-pip-74lvc1g386:74LVC1G386 or http://www.marutsu.co.jp/contents/shop/marutsu/datasheet/2500002817197.pdf

Comment: @J.Sherman They are not part of the standard and if you look at it actually is a controlled XOR gate with first input is inverting the XOR or alternatively cascaded XOR + AND.

Comment: I'm not clear what standard (IEEE?) you are referring to, but it would be simpler to have a 3 input XOR option than making a cascaded XOR + AND every time. In any case, its not as if the tikzpicture is a functional circuit.  And from a coding standpoint, Is there some way I can redefine an XOR gate using the same code as an OR gate, just with a different "base" image?  Should I make this a different question?